# Check if QTextStream::operator>> failed

Tags: c++, qt

Functions like `sscanf` return the number of successfully read items, which is useful for error checking, for example the code below would print "failed" because sscanf would return 3 (1, 2, 3 were read, but "text" was not a number).

Does `QTextStream` offer an equivalent way for error-checking?

```
const char *text = "1 2 3 text";
int a, b, c, d;
if (4 != sscanf(text, "%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d))
    printf("failed");
QString text2 = text;
QTextStream stream(&text2);
stream >> a >> b >> c >> d; // how do I know that d could not be assigned?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the [stream's status](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#Status-enum) after reading by calling `stream.status()`:

```
if (stream.status() == QTextStream::Ok) 
{
    // succeeded
} 
else
{
    // failed
}
```

Comment: How do they do that? I thought `operator >>` returned a reference to *this so nesting can be done

Comment: @satuon: By overloading operator bool or operator void* or something that can be converted to bool

Comment: @satuon I don't know about Qt (or whether it even supports it), but normal `std` streams have a conversion operator to `void*`, which returns a null pointer iff the stream is in failed state.

Comment: this doesn't compile - when using `if (stream >> a) {}` it gives me `error: could not convert 'stream.QTextStream::operator>>(((int&)(& a)))' to 'bool'`

Comment: @satuon: OK then, apparently Qt streams don't support this. You can still use the second part of my answer - the status

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, that sscanf check was probably not enough :-(

In a lot of cases, developers will want to look for more errors, like overflows, etc.

```
const char *text = "1 2 3 9999999999";
int a, b, c, d;
if (4 != sscanf(text, "%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d))
    printf("failed");
printf("Numbers: %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
// But because of an overflow error, that code can
// print something unexpected, like: 1 2 3 1410065407
// instead of "failed"
```

Auxiliary strings can be used to detect input errors, for example:

```
const char *text = "1 9999999999 text";
QString item1, item2, item3, item4;
QTextStream stream(text);
stream >> item1 >> item2 >> item3 >> item4;
int a, b, c, d;
bool conversionOk; // Indicates if the conversion was successful
a = item1.toInt(&conversionOk);
if (conversionOk == false)
    cerr << "Error 1." << endl;

b = item2.toInt(&conversionOk);
if (conversionOk == false)
    cerr << "Error 2." << endl;

c = item3.toInt(&conversionOk);
if (conversionOk == false)
    cerr << "Error 3." << endl;

d = item4.toInt(&conversionOk);
if (conversionOk == false)
    cerr << "Error 4." << endl;
```

will print "Error 2.", "Error 3." and "Error 4.".

Note: cin, cout and cerr can also be defined there as:

```
QTextStream cin(stdin, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream cerr(stderr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
```